# Need to convert Dataframe data into Nested dictionaries include list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created Data Frame, Check below snippet.

```
data = {'id': [101,102],
        'name': ['xyz', 'xyz'],
        'value1' : [41,42],
        'value2' : [42,32]
        }
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'name','value1','value2'])
print(df)
```

**Output of Dataframe**

```
id     name   value1  value2
101     xyz     41     42
102     xyy     42     32
```

**Here I just want to create nested dictionary from this Data Frame.**

**Expected output**

```
{'101':{'name':'xyz'
            'data' : [{'value1' : 41,'value2':42},
                       {'value1': 42,'value2':32}]}}
```

I tried to do by following code but it's won't work so  please could you me solve this

#Tried Snippet

**code**

```
print({n: grp.loc[n].to_dict('index')for n, grp in df.set_index(['id','name']).group by(level='id')})
```

**output**

```
{101: {'xyz': {'value1': 41, 'value2': 42}}, 102: {'xyz': {'value1': 42, 'value2': 32}}}
```

**code**

```
print({k:f.groupby('name')['value1'].apply(list).to_dict() for k, f in df.groupby('id')})
```

**output**

```
{101: {'xyz': [41]}, 102: {'xyz': [42]}}
```

**required output**

```
{'101':{'name':'xyz'
            'data' : [{'value1' : 41,'value2':42},
                       {'value1': 42,'value2':32},
                      ]}}
```

Comment: ```df.groupby('id')[['name', 'value1', 'value2']].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('name').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say **df** is :

**df:**

```
    id name  value1  value2
0  101  xyz      41      42
1  102  xyy      42      32
2  101  xyz      46      46
3  102  xyy      40      39
```

---

```
df.groupby(['id', 'name'])[['value1', 'value2']] \ 
.apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records')).reset_index(name='data')\
.set_index('id').to_dict(orient='index')
```

---

`{101: {'name': 'xyz',                                                                                                     'data': [{'value1': 41, 'value2': 42}, {'value1': 46, 'value2': 46}]},                                                      102: {'name': 'xyy',                                                                                                     'data': [{'value1': 42, 'value2': 32}, {'value1': 40, 'value2': 39}]}}`

Comment: Hope this helps. If this helps then accept this as an accepted answer by clicking on the tick.